# Add columns from one dataframe to another based on several conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code which:

1. Separates dataframes one for all years between 2005 and 2014 and another dataframe for 2015 alone.
2. Then I get the min max per day across all weather stations.

Finally I need to add the min and max of df2015 to df so I can compare if in year 2015 the min and max per day broke the previous 10 days min or max.

```
 df = pd.read_csv('data/C2A2_data/BinnedCsvs_d400/fb441e62df2d58994928907a91895ec62c2c42e6cd075c2700843b89.csv'.format(binsize))
    df['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
    df = df.sort_values(['Date', 'ID'], ascending=[True, False])
    df['day'] = df['Date'].dt.day
    df['month'] = df['Date'].dt.month
    df['year'] = df['Date'].dt.year
    df = df[df['year'] < 2015]
    df = df.groupby(['month','day'])['Data_Value'].agg(['min', 'max']) 
    print(df)
    
    df2015 = pd.read_csv('data/C2A2_data/BinnedCsvs_d400/fb441e62df2d58994928907a91895ec62c2c42e6cd075c2700843b89.csv'.format(binsize))
    df2015['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df2015['Date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
    df2015 = df2015.sort_values(['Date', 'ID'], ascending=[True, False])
    df2015['day'] = df2015['Date'].dt.day
    df2015['month'] = df2015['Date'].dt.month
    df2015['year'] = df2015['Date'].dt.year
    df2015 = df2015[df2015['year'] == 2015]
    df2015 = df2015.groupby(['month','day'])['Data_Value'].agg(['min', 'max']) 
    df2015.rename(columns = {'min':'min2015'}, inplace = True)
    df2015.rename(columns = {'max':'max2015'}, inplace = True)
    print(df2015)
```

so basically I need to add min2015 and max2015 columns to the df based on month and day column

each dataframe looks like this:

```
 min  max
month day          
1     1   -160  156
      2   -267  139
      3   -267  133
      4   -261  106




  min2015  max2015
month day                  
1     1       -133       11
      2       -122       39
      3        -67       39
```